# Pandas to latex, cannot drop index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, latex

I'm trying to drop my row numbering when I export a pandas (ver 1.4.3) dataframe to latex code. I've found that I should include the command 'index=False'. However when I run my code I get an error that the styler does not include 'index'.

error code:

```
  File "/home/-/GitHub/-/latex/step1_feet_bottom.py", line 43, in get_feet
    excel = excel.to_latex(index=False,

TypeError: Styler.to_latex() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

This is my code:

```
latex = df.copy()
latex = latex.round(1)
latex = latex.style.format(na_rep='-', precision=1)
latex = latex.to_latex(index=False,
    column_format="rrrrr", position="h", position_float="centering",
    hrules=True, label="table:5", caption="Styled LaTeX Table",
    multirow_align="t", multicol_align="r"
    )  
print(latex)
```

One weird thing is the following, if I include na_rep='-' in to_latex I get the same error. My first guess was that I was running an old version of pandas, I am however running the latest [version 1.4.3](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [`Styler.to_latex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex) is different to [`DataFrame.to_latex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_latex). Whilst index is a valid argument for `DataFrame.to_latex()`, it is not a valid argument for `Styler.to_latex()`, and neither is `na_rep`

Comment: you should use `latex.style.format(na_rep='-', precision=1).hide(axis="index").to_latex(**kwargs)`